# Comparing realtime audio with the recorded in Android

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency

I want to make an android application in which i am going to record the sound when water flowing through a pipe and then compare it with a stored sound. This comparison is to be performed realtime. I have applied windowing and FFT on the sounds, and then calculated spectral flux to understand the sudden spikes between frames. But when taking the average of realtime audio and recorded audio, seems the difference is as low as negligible.

Is there any way to calculate narrow and wide spikes in a sound? or is there any good way to compare realtime sound with the recorded in java.If anyone has some information regarding this so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think i you can use the cross correlation to do this. This is a video that explain this very good: [Cross Correlation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r_fDlM0Dx0)